# Array2D to Array

Tags: f#

I have Array2D of 0 and 1:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let a = Array2D.init n n (fun i j  -> int(System.Math.Round(rnd.NextDouble() / index)) )
```

I need to calculate the count of '1'-elements, something like:

```
a |> Array.filter (fun x -> x == 1)
```

But 'a' is Array2D (not Array) so I'm just wondering if there is a standard way to transform Array2D to Array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one easy way, using the fact that `[,]` implements `ienumerable<_>`

```
a |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x == 1)
```

but if you only need the count you can do

```
a |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.sum
```

as the 0 terms won't add to the sum and the terms you want to count are just 1

Answer (score 7):

The function transforming from Array2D to Array is very handy in many situations.

You can keep it in `Array2D` module for convenient use.

```
module Array2D =
    let toArray (arr: 'T [,]) = arr |> Seq.cast<'T> |> Seq.toArray
```