# F# converting Array2D to array of arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#

In F# is there a concise way of converting a float[,] to float[][]? In case this seems like a stupid thing to do it is so I can use Array.zip on the resulting array of arrays. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array2D to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870368/array2d-to-array)

Comment: @Ringil: not really a duplicate because the 2d array is being flattened in the other question.

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick:

```
module Array2D = 
    let toJagged<'a> (arr: 'a[,]) : 'a [][] = 
        [| for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 arr - 1 do
               yield [| for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 arr - 1 -> arr.[x, y] |]
            |]
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `Array2D` can have a base other than zero. For every dimension, we can utilize an initializing function taking its base and length. This may be a locally scoped operator:

```
let toArray arr =
    let ($) (bas, len) f = Array.init len ((+) bas >> f)
    (Array2D.base1 arr, Array2D.length1 arr) $ fun x ->
        (Array2D.base2 arr, Array2D.length2 arr) $ fun y ->
            arr.[x, y]
// val toArray : arr:'a [,] -> 'a [] []
```

I fail to see how to generalize for a subsequent application of `Array.zip`, since that would imply a length of 2 in one dimension.