# F# - Convert Jagged Array to Array2D

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#, jagged-arrays

@scrwtp provides a very useful function ([toJagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842353/f-converting-array2d-to-array-of-arrays)):

```
let toJagged<'a> (arr: 'a[,]) : 'a [][] = 
    [| for x in 0 .. Array2D.length1 arr - 1 do
           yield [| for y in 0 .. Array2D.length2 arr - 1 -> arr.[x, y] |]
    |]
```

that converts from a 2D array to a jagged array. Is there an equivalent function available (*toArray2D*) for converting from a jagged array to a 2D array (assuming each row in the jagged array has the same number of elements)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a built-in function `array2D` that does exactly this:

```
array2D 
  [| [| 1; 2 |]
     [| 3; 4 |] |]
```

The `array2D` function has a type `seq<#seq<'T>> -> 'T[,]` so it is more general - it can convert any sequence of sequences of values to a 2D array, but since a jagged array *is* a sequence of sequences, this is all you need. Note that this throws if your nested arrays have different lengths.