# f# flattening a 2d array to 1d array

Tags: f#

How do you flatten a 2d array to a 1d array by appending each row to the one above?

My problem is not understanding how to use map to do this as other functional languages have a flatmap/(insert similar name here) function to do this.

```
let colors = Array2D.init 800 480 (fun i j -> 
    if i % 3 = 0 || j % 3 = 0 then Color.Black
    else Color.Red)
let data = colors |> map (fun c -> c)
```

How woulds I use map such that the return type from the map is changed to a 1d array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array2D to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870368/array2d-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to flatten it you can cast it to a seq:

```
colors  |> Seq.cast<Color> 
        |> Seq.length //val it : int = 384000
```

There might be something in Array2D that's more convenient but Array2D is really a .NET collection. You can work with ragged arrays or lists and then you can have access to `Seq.concat` or `collect`.

**Add1**

Here it is already in a 1D List:

```
let colors = [for i in 0..799 do
                 for j in 0..479 ->
                 if (i % 3 = 0) || (j % 3 = 0) then Color.Black
                 else Color.Red]
```

**With Active Patterns**

Depending on the actual complexity this might also be a good candidate for [active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns). Below an active recognizer for Black and Red is defined, together with the pattern matching, then the 2D List is generated which is fed to [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.concat%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), and finally checked against the original Array2D. You don't need to work with Lists of course (e.g. can be seq for laziness or Array for performance).

```
let (|Black|Red|) input = if fst input % 3 = 0 || snd input % 3 = 0 then Black else Red
let matchColor =
    function 
    |Black -> Color.Black
    |Red -> Color.Red
let color3 = List.init 800 (fun i -> List.init 480 (fun j -> matchColor (i,j)))

let color4 = color3 |> List.concat
color4 |> Seq.length

colors
 |> Array2D.mapi (fun i j x -> color3.[i].[j] = colors.[i,j])
 |> Seq.cast<bool>
 |> Seq.filter not
```

Answer (score 4):

for Sequences use Seq.fold + Seq.append + empty Seq

```
let seq2d = seq {yield seq{1..3}; yield seq{4..6} }
seq2d |> Seq.fold Seq.append Seq.empty<int>
//[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6;]
```

or even less typing with just Seq.reduce + Seq.append

```
seq2d |> Seq.reduce Seq.append
//[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6;]
```

for lists (but not Sequences) it's List.reduce + List.append

```
let list2d = [ [1;2;3]; [4;5] ]
list2d |> List.reduce List.append
//[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```