# F# go through structure

Tags: arrays, loops, f#, structure

I've created a structure.And in a loop I fill array with elements of this type. How can I go through this array, and get a sum of the elements?

```
type LAB = 
    struct 
        val L:float
        val A:float
        val B: float
        new (l:float,a:float,b:float) = {L= l; A =a; B=b}
    end

let RGBtoLAB(map: Bitmap) =
    let m1 = matrix [[ 0.3811; 0.5783; 0.0402 ]
                     [ 0.1967; 0.7244; 0.0782 ]
                     [ 0.0241; 0.1288; 0.8444 ]]

    let m2 = matrix [[ 0.5774; 0.5774; 0.5774 ]
                     [ 0.4082; 0.4082; -0.8164 ]
                     [ 0.7071; -0.7071; 0.0 ]]

    let lab = Array2D.zeroCreate map.Width map.Height
    for i=0 to map.Width-1 do
        for j=0 to map.Height-1 do
            let R = checkColor(map.GetPixel(i,j).R)
            let G = checkColor(map.GetPixel(i,j).G)
            let B = checkColor(map.GetPixel(i,j).B)
            let v = vector [R;G;B]
            let lms = m1*v
            let lmsLog = lms |> Vector.map (fun c -> Math.Log10(c))
            lab.[i,j] <- LAB((m2*lmsLog).Item(0),(m2*lmsLog).Item(1),(m2*lmsLog).Item(2))
    lab
```

Thanks for answers

Comment: Can you please show your attempts and their results?

Comment: Fyodor Soikin, I've done like this, but want to do this in functional style     
 for i=0 to w-1 do
        for j=0 to h-1 do
           E.E1<-E.E1+lab.[i,j].L
           E.E2<-E.E2+lab.[i,j].A 
           E.E3<-E.E3+lab.[i,j].B

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution from [Array2D to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870368/array2d-to-array) to convert Array2D to the sequence and then use [Seq.fold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.fold%5B't,'state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) as described.